# current() VS list() on each()

Tags: php, php-5.6, php-7.2

I'm trying to get rid of deprecated code on a PHP7.2 web server by replacing the following code:

```
list(, $block) = each($this->blocks);
```

with that:

```
$block = current($this->_blocks);
```

I am not expecting any differences. Tests on simple arrays return the same results. Can anyone sees how it could be a problem ?

Comment: Warning! `$this->blocks` !== `$this->_blocks`

Comment: This looks like a good reason to start writing automated tests :) If you don't have any, why not simply run your application and see what happens?